# getting Can't set headers after they are sent using node with very simple script

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I had written a js script in Node that was quite complex and worked. I upgraded my server and found it failed. In going back to basics, I find that this simple script fails with a console message, as shown below it, when I go to http://www.mapworldlive.com:8899/test from my browser:

```
var http = require("http");
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.on('request', app);
server.listen(8899);
var chttime=new Date(),showdate=chttime.toDateString(),secs=chttime.getSeconds(),mins=chttime.getMinutes(),hrs=chttime.getHours(),day=chttime.getDay(),month=chttime.getMonth(),year=chttime.getFullYear();
console.log("Test Server started: "+hrs+":"+mins+" "+showdate);

app.use('/test',function(req, res) {
   console.log("hello world")
   res.end()
})
```

Response:

```
Test Server started: 14:23 Sat Feb 04 2017
hello world
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Please help me so that others may be helped in my situation!

Stack Trace:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11)
    at expressInit (/var/www/vhosts/mapworldlive.com/dev.mapworldlive.com/node_modules/express/lib/
iddleware/init.js:23:42)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/vhosts/mapworldlive.com/dev.mapworldlive.com/node
modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/var/www/vhosts/mapworldlive.com/dev.mapworldlive.com/node_modules/express/lib/
outer/index.js:312:13)
    at /var/www/vhosts/mapworldlive.com/dev.mapworldlive.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.
s:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/var/www/vhosts/mapworldlive.com/dev.mapworldlive.com/node_modules/
xpress/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/var/www/vhosts/mapworldlive.com/dev.mapworldlive.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/
ndex.js:271:10)
    at query (/var/www/vhosts/mapworldlive.com/dev.mapworldlive.com/node_modules/express/lib/middle
are/query.js:44:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/vhosts/mapworldlive.com/dev.mapworldlive.com/node
modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/var/www/vhosts/mapworldlive.com/dev.mapworldlive.com/node_modules/express/lib/
outer/index.js:312:13)
```

Comment: is this all the code?

Comment: I stripped everything back for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two lines are basically the same:

```
var server = http.createServer(app);

server.on('request', app);
```

So my guess is that you're running your request handling twice, the second one finds that the first has already called `response.end`.

Remove the `server.on` and retry. Also a personal hint: don't call `res.end` but output something to the browser so you can test easily, like `res.send('Hi!')`.